# How this piece of code accessing the local variable outside the C++ function?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, local

```
int * addition(int arr[])
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    sum+=arr[i];
    return &sum;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[4]{1,3,4,5}, * ptr=addition(arr);
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As the variable `sum` is local to the function `addition` so the variable should be destroyed as soon as the program control moves out of the function but it is still giving the output `13`. Why?

```
Compiler: g++ 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable sum is on the stack. When the function addition() returns it doesn't zero the released stack memory, so the address returned still contains the sum.

Does it still work if you enable optimisation with -O3 ?

Comment: No it is not working with -O3 level of optimization. Why?